# Javascript AJAX POST Method not posting values to the submitted page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using Javascript AJAX to send request a php page and receiving the output from php page. When I use `GET` method in AJAX, its working. but the same is not working when i use `POST` method.

**here is my code:**

```
<script>
function verifyMobile(mobileNo,code,emailKey)
{
    alert(mobileNo+'-'+code+'-'+emailKey); //alerts proper value here...
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {

alert(xmlhttp.responseText); //alerts empty value here...

          }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","verification.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send("mobileNo="+mobileNo+"&code="+code+"&emailKey="+emailKey);
}
</script>
```

**verification.php**

```
<?php
$mobile_number=trim($_POST['mobileNo']);
$sms_code=trim($_POST['code']);
$email_key=trim($_POST['emailKey']);
echo $mobile_number." - ".$sms_code." - ".$email_key;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the headers and see if it helps.

```
var params = "mobileNo="+encodeURIComponent(mobileNo)+"&code="+encodeURIComponent(code)+"&emailKey="+encodeURIComponent(emailKey);
xmlhttp.open("POST","verification.php",true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
xmlhttp.send(params);
```

Comment: why do we need `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close"); `